# Building a JFrame that run in the same order in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm making a `JFrame` that contains a lot of `JButton`s and `JTextfield`s which contain data from a database. In the design everything is okay, but when I run my program the `JButton` and the `JTextfield` change their places and I don't know why.

Here is a screen shot from the design window and the run window:

[image: Screenshot of design window]

[image: Screenshot of runtime window]

Comment: Your JTextAreas seem to be shorter than your buttons, so they're becoming misaligned. Check your setBounds() or setSize() calls. We also need your source to help more than that, so add it to your answer.

Comment: i don't use setBounds or setSize. I build it from the swing controls and change the size by my hand. Any help?

Comment: Even if you didn't write the calls, whatever window building software you used did. Post the source in your answer, then we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the JTextAreas are shorter than the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have aligned the textfields to each other and the buttons too. But you should have aligned one button to one textfield. One way to do this would be to use a `GridBagLayout` instead of the FreeDesign option in NetBeans. To do this right-click onto your frame and select Set Layout>Grid Bag Layout.
You can then right-click again and select Customize Layout... in order to place your components as you wish.